# Furstenberg's topological proof of infinitude of primes

Tags: general-topology, number-theory, prime-numbers

There's fairly well-known proof of infinitude of prime numbers by using *topology* by Furstenberg. ([Here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/primestopology.pdf) is K.Conrad's note about the proof). As we can see in the last section, Furstenberg's *topological* proof is actually not topological, but only uses the terminology. In fact, it is almost same as Euclid's famous argument.

So I have some questions about this proof, especially some possible generalizations.

1) How far can we generalize this to an arbitrary (infinite) ring? I think we can prove that there are infinitely many irreducible elements in $\mathcal{O}_{K}$, a ring of integer of some number field $K$, by using the same argument with suitable modification. Also, it seems possible to prove that any $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ has infinitely many prime ideals, at least if it has finitely many units (like totally imaginary fields).

2) Can we really prove something related to topology by using a similar argument? For example, by defining a suitable topology on some set $X$, can we prove that there are infinitely many *irreducible* subsets, or elements in $X$, where *irreducible* may depend on context? For example, can we prove that there are infinitely many prime geodesics on a hyperbolic surface by defining some suitable topology on it? (I think this is not a good example)

Thanks in advance.